# Angular apollo - UI doesn't update after doing a query mutation update

Tags: angular, angular6, apollo-client

I'm working on an angular 6 app, using angular apollo.  The issue I'm facing is that the UI does not update after deleting some items and updating the local apollo cache.  I'm fetching a list of appointments from the server, and the user can delete them.  When they delete I send a mutation to delete the item, which works fine, then I want to update the local cached query so it's removed from the UI.  The relevant code looks like:

Getting the appts from the server:

```
this.appointments$ = this.getArtistByUserIdGQL.watch({userId: params.id}).valueChanges
  .pipe(
    map(results => results.data.user),
    tap(this.setUser.bind(this)),
    switchMap(user => {
      return this.artistAppointmentBookGQL.watch({artistId: user.artist._id, filter}).valueChanges
        .pipe(
          map(results => results.data.artist.appointmentBook)
        );
    }),
    catchError(err => throwError(err))
  );
```

Rendering the appointments in the UI:

```
  <div class="row appt-book-records"
       *ngIf="(appointments$ | async) as appointments">
    <div *ngIf="(filter$ | async) as filter" class="col">
      <ul class="list-group"
          *ngIf="appointments.length">
        <li *ngFor="let appt of appointments"
            class="appointment-book-item list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
            <button (click)="deleteAppt(appt._id)">Click to delete</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And finally the delete mutation:

```
  deleteAppt(apptId: string) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this appointment?  This can not be undone.')) {
      this.deleteAppointmentGQL.mutate({id: apptId}, {
        update: this.updateCache.bind(this, apptId)
      }).subscribe();
    }
  }
```

And the actual update method:

```
 updateCache(apptId, store, {data: {deleteAppointment}}) {
    if (deleteAppointment.success) {
      const vars = {artistId: this.user.artist._id, filter: this.filter},
        query = new StoreManager<ArtistAppointmentBook.Query>(store, this.artistAppointmentBookGQL.document, vars);

      query.data.artist.appointmentBook =
        query.data.artist.appointmentBook.filter(appointment => appointment._id !== apptId);

      query.write();
    }
  }
```

The StoreManager bits are just doing a readQuery and writeQuery with the new filtered list of data. As far as I can tell this is doing what it should be, because if I navigate away and then back to the view *without* refreshing the page, it works and the local cache shows that the appointment was deleted.  So, am I doing something wrong in my angular UI that is causing it not to update after I update the query?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've also tried wrapping various bits of the `updateCache` and `deleteAppt` in an `NgZone.run` call, but it doesn't change the outcome.  The UI does not update.

Comment: do you get a new query result in watch observable?

Comment: If you mean, does the inner query run again, negative.  I added a `tap` in the inner pipe to just log to the console what was happening,  and nothing occurs after setting the new query value.

Comment: In an interesting update, even though I'm deleting, I just tried pushing something to the array just to see if it would update, and it did indeed update the UI.  So something about setting that internal property of the query seems to be problematic.